# UINavigationController disable Language direction in swipe to go back

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

When the application language is Arabic, (interactivePopGestureRecognizer) works from right to left so the user has to swipe from right edge to pop viewController.I wanna to force interactivePopGestureRecognizer to swipe from left to right (user has to swipe from left edge) despite the app language because I wanna to fix the back button at left side at both English and Arabic languages.
I have used `[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight] ;` but this has fixed half of the problem as it made the interactivePopGestureRecognizer in Arabic language swipes from left to right but the user still swipe from right edge.Any suggestion???

Comment: Why are you doing this? Do you have an in-app language switcher?

Comment: Yes, I've. I am doing that because I am manually switch the language because I do not want the app to be closed when the user switch the language.

Comment: This is not recommended. Your users will be very confused to find out that your app is not respecting the system language.

Comment: Yes don't handle localisation manually within the app, go by what the OS does for localisation change.

Comment: @SamehDos have you found any solution? Im facing the same problem.

Comment: @SamehDos [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight] ; this thing works above iOS 9. how can you implement it anyway on iOS 7 and iOS 8 ?